# How can I play an MP3 file in a cross-platform bash script?

Tags: bash, cross-platform, mp3

I want to play an MP3 file in a simple bash script. I want my bash script to be able to work on any OS or distro, so I don't want to lock it down to any particular MP3 software. How can I easily play the MP3 with whatever MP3-playing software happens to be available?

Answer (score 1):

I've written a simple script to check from a big list of known MP3 tools to see if any of them are installed (using [the POSIX-standard "command -v" tool](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/utilities/command.html)). As soon as the script finds an MP3 program that it recognizes, that program will be used to simply play the file (with no console output, if possible) and then exit. (footnote: cvlc, the last player in the list, will open the gui program VLC to play the file, then automatically close it. If that's not acceptable to you, I recommend removing cvlc from the list.)

This script is pretty much guaranteed to work perfectly on Ubuntu and Mac OS X (which ship with ffmpeg and afplay respectively), and is highly likely to work on other platforms. In the unlikely event that no MP3 software is found, a message is printed to stderr (this message includes the [BEL character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character)).

If you need an absolute 100% guarantee that the MP3 will be played (or you need more options like volume control), you should probably require that your users install ffmpeg or something. But for quick-and-dirty sound effects in a relatively simple script, this might be the perfect quick fix!

Anyway, enough rambling, here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# playmp3 by Hayden Schiff (oxguy3)
#
# Play an MP3 with whatever MP3 software is already installed.
# Do whatever you want with this; the license is WTFPL.
#
# Usage:  playmp3 filename.mp3
#    or:  playmp3 /path/to/file.mp3

player=""
declare -a players=(
    "afplay" # OS X built-in
    "ffplay -nodisp" # ffmpeg
    "mpg123 --quiet"
    "maplay"
    "mplayer -really-quiet -noconsolecontrols"
    "play -V1" # SoX
    "cvlc --play-and-exit" # VLC curses interface
)

for p in "${players[@]}"; do
    pBase=$(echo $p | cut -d' ' -f1)
    if command -v $pBase >/dev/null; then
        player="$p"
        break
    fi
done

if [ -n "$player" ]; then
    $player $@
else
    >&2 echo -e "\aCould not find an MP3 player"
fi
```

If you don't want to include "playmp3" as a separate file, you can embed this in your bash script by removing the hashbang (the very first line of the script), and surrounding the rest of the script with `function playmp3() {` and `}` respectively.

If updates are ever made to this script, they will appear [in my GitHub repo](https://github.com/oxguy3/scripts/blob/master/bin/playmp3) (though I will try to remember to keep this post on StackOverflow up-to-date).

Comment: I believe using `open` (and possibly `xdg-open`) will do much of what this does but including using the user's configured desktop preferences. Though that might be to launch a GUI application and not play it "in the background".

Comment: Yeah, `open` would use a GUI tool in most cases, which is really undesirable for my uses. This only resorts to a GUI tool if there's truly nothing else available.